# Is there a way to specify classes that have a specific annotation?

Tags: java, syntax, annotations

Okay, so:

`Class<? extends YourCustomClass> clazz` only accepts classes that extend **YourCustomClass**.
`Class<? extends YourCustomInterface> interfaze` only accepts classes that implement **YourCustomInterface**.

Is there an equivalent for Annotations that does the same thing, because `Class<? extends YourCustomAnnotation> annotation` only accepts annotations that extend **YourCustomAnnotation**...

And no, I don't want to filter packages for annotated classes during code execution, so the reflection-API won't help.

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: **No**, annotations are additional metadata. In a (maven) build one could do an annotation scan  So in a post-compilation phase you could check it. With reflection as you mentioned. And did not want. A regex multiline search could find violations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using a javac plug-in such as the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org).
Section [Restricting instantiation of a generic class](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#generics-instantiation) in its
[manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/) gives the following example.

> You can write a type qualifier on the extends clause to make the upper bound a qualified type. For example, you can declare that a generic list class can hold only non-null values:

```
  class MyList<T extends @NonNull Object> {...}

  MyList<@NonNull String> m1;       // OK
  MyList<@Nullable String> m2;      // error
```

> That is, in the above example, all arguments that replace `T` in `MyList<T>` must be subtypes of `@NonNull Object`.

The Checker Framework also supports [wildcards](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#annotations-on-wildcards) as in your example.